# Openapi YAML wrong, cannot generate client-stubs

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I'm evaluating Quarkus as backend, accessed by an angular frontend.
I wanted to use the openapi data provided by Quarkus via http://localhost:8080/openapi,
and generate via openapi-generator tools an typescript-angular client stub.

I used as first step the Quarkus Openapi Guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui
But after running the unmodified example and retrieve the Openapi YAML-Data via the http://localhost:8080/openapi I noticed that the generated data is wrong and the openapi generator is not able to generate a client because of a stackoverflow error.

Problem: a self-reference in the Openapi-data for the SetFruit-Definition (last line):

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Generated API
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /fruits:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SetFruit'
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Fruit'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SetFruit'
    delete:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Fruit'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SetFruit'
components:
  schemas:
    Fruit:
      type: object
      properties:
        description:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
    SetFruit:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/SetFruit'
```

Is this a known problem, or is there some misunderstanding on my side.
Is there a way to work around this issue?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Could you raise an issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues with a project that reproduces the problem?

The team can then investigate what the problem might be

Comment: okay, done it: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7238

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely not be generating a self-referencing definition!  Could you perhaps open up an issue here:

https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/issues

That library is the implementation behind the Quarkus support for this feature.  If you could include a reproducer project that would be very helpful.  Or at the very least give us some information about the `Fruit` and `SetFruit` java classes.

Comment: okay, done: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be solved in Quarkus 1.3.0.CR1, released next week.